# Swap Red and Blue Pixels of Image

Tags: python, image, for-loop, filter, pixel

I am trying to create a function that will allow me to swap every red and blue pixel of an image. However, when running the function, new image does not change or do the intended. So far, I am only trying to change the image to only blue filter to test the function.

```
from CSE8AImage import *
img = load_img('images/cat.jpg')

def complement(img):
    
    for r in range(len(img)): 
        for c in range(len(img[r])):
            pix = img[r][c]
            img[r][c] = (0, 0, pix[2]) 

    return img

save_img(img, 'complement_cat.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing in your code is simply setting the red and green pixels to 0(assuming it's RGB? I couldn't find anything about the CSE8AImage library outside of [this page which perfectly matches your question](https://www.coursehero.com/tutors-problems/Python-Programming/41295865-Please-conduct-a-python-image-transformation-function-that/)). I will continue assuming it's in RGB.

What you should change in your code to make it work is simply change `img[r][c] = (0,0,pix[2])` to `img[r][c] = pix[[2,1,0]]` as this is saying to reorder the pixels (RGB, index 0,1,2) to the new order (BGR, index 2,1,0).

A simpler way would just be to do the whole array at once:

```
def complement(img):
    return img[:,:,[2,1,0]]
```

This will only work if you can index it like an array in python. Ignore this if this is not the case.

Comment: Yeah, the library is from a UCSD course and I have already downloaded/imported the library to work with IDLE. Also the pixels are in RGB. However, I am trying to practice with for nested loops. Anyways, I am going to try doing the re-order code that you suggested. (which honestly I don't know why I didn't think of that haha, seems so obvious lol).

Comment: So far, I tried the code you suggested, but problem is, when I access the new image in the library, there is no change/difference from the original. Is it because the I am not applying the function on the shell?

Comment: oh yes, your save_img function is just saving the original image. Change it to `save_img(complement(img), 'complement_cat.jpg')`

Comment: dammit. why didn't I think of that! Thank you!!